# Bookmark PdfOutline Exception Issue on Close of Document

Tags: itext

I have an interesting problem when generating PDFs. I introduced bookmarks into PDF recently and noticed problems when closing document. Lets begin with a sample code of what is happening.

```
private static String CONTENT = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\n" +
        "\n" +
        "Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.\n" +
        "\n" +
        "Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.\n" +
        "\n" +
        "Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\n" +
        "\n" +
        "Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.\n" +
        "\n" +
        "At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.\n";

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Document document = new Document();
    try
    {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
        document.open();
        PdfOutline root = writer.getRootOutline();

        int i = 0;
        PdfDestination destination = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ);
        PdfOutline outline = new PdfOutline(root, destination, "Section 1");
        writer.getDirectContent().localDestination(""+(i++), destination);
        document.add(new Paragraph(CONTENT));

        document.newPage();

        destination = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ);
        outline = new PdfOutline(root, destination, "Section 2");
        writer.getDirectContent().localDestination(""+(i++), destination);

        document.close();

        PDFEmbeddedManager manager = new PDFEmbeddedManager();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TEST");
        frame.setSize(1024, 768);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(manager.getFormView(), BorderLayout.CENTER);


        manager.showPDF(baos.toByteArray(), "");

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    catch (DocumentException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Right after we add CONTENT into document, you will notice a newPage() statement then followed by an outline. This is where trouble begins. When I try to close document we get an exception which I see is meant by design in close() for PdfWriter. But if we remove the bookmark after newPage() all is well and no exception.

Now for my question, what is a good way for us to continue adding bookmarks/outline after a newPage() which will allow us to close the document without exception? Is there a way for us to go through all the bookmarks/outline fixing their destination to point to the last page instead of a page which doesn't exist? Any help and insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: The page 2 was requested but the document has only 1 pages.
```

**EDIT 2:**

Mainly, what I would like to achieve is show Section 2 in the bookmarks even if Section 2 had content or not. As a result of calling newPage() at the end of Section 1, then adding Section 2 Outline but not adding content, exception is thrown. Is there any way for me to still add Section 2 outline / bookmark and not having to worry whether Section 2 will add content to the new page?

Answer (score 2):

I was going to update mkl's answer, but in the end I decided to add an extra answer, because the issue has a very specific cause that needs to be clarified.

Your exception tells you that you are trying to link to page 2 but that the document only has one page. Why does your document only have one page?

When you trigger `document.newPage()` a new page is only created if the current page isn't blank. This is by design because `newPage()` is also triggered by iText internally and past experiences have taught us that this often led to unwanted blank pages.

If you want to override this *without* adding content (as suggested by mkl), you can use the following line:

```
writer.setPageEmpty(false);
```

When a new page is create the flag `pageEmpty` is `true` until you add content. You can set this flag to `false` with the `setPageEmpty()` method. If you do this, your document will have more than 1 page. See the [NewPage](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=99) example to find out how the mechanism works.

Comment: What happens is we have many sections we add to a PDF; some sections might not be added while others are added. Each sections ends with a newPage() to prepare the next section. Basically, our problem is we would like to see a bookmark on where a section is supposed to be whether any content was added by it or not and the outlines are added first before a section is processed. An example, Add Ouline for Section A and its content to PDF and newPage(). Section B outline added but no content, close document->exception. Any ideas on what we can do? We would like to see bookmark for Section B.

Comment: Also, I would prefer to leave the setPageEmpty() to true as more than one section can possibly call newPage() continually without adding a single piece of content.

Comment: *Also, I would prefer to leave the setPageEmpty() to true* - in that case make sure you add content after you set the final destination, cf. My answer, e.g. a final page with a centered "the end". Or use the setPageEmpty trick only at the end of the document, right before close.

Answer (score 1):

> what is a good way for us to continue adding bookmarks/outline after a newPage() which will allow us to close the document without exception?

Using the outline after a `newPage()` does not suffice to trigger your issue. It is essential that you do not add any content after that `newPage()`, only the bookmark.

The following happens:

- `newPage()` makes iText finish the current (first) page and start a new (second) one in memory.
- `localDestination(...)` initializes the destination to point to the now current page 2.
- At `close()` there still is no content on the now current page 2 and it, therefore, is not written to the PDF.
- In `close()` while writing the bookmarks, iText sees that there is a bookmark destination on a non-existing page and throws an exception.

You can easily prevent that exception from occurring by adding content to the document after setting a destination, e.g.

```
    ...
    writer.getDirectContent().localDestination(""+(i++), destination);
    document.add(new Paragraph("x")); // <<<<< Adds content to the page the destination points to

    document.close();
```

works just fine.

**Thus, *a good way to continue adding bookmarks/outline after a `newPage()`* is to make sure that you add content after setting a bookmark destination.**